# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I've build my applications (3 of them) in eclipse. Now, the new ADT plug-in (v23.02) has been released and I can't update. So I decided to try the Android Studio, but I can't figure out how to import my projects. I tried to export my applications with Gradle, but I can't export an application without appcompat_vx (the Next button is not avalabile). So when I sellect to export MyApplicationV1 it requires appcompat_vx, and when I select them both the next button can't be pressed. Any advices? Thank you!

Solved: By choosing Open Project from Android Studio and pointing to Eclipse Projects folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to export them from Eclipse with the latest version of Android Studio. I too used Android Studio for the first time yesterday.

In Android Studio go to Import Project and point it to your eclipse project directory. This will create a project within Android Studio with your Eclipse project as a module of it.

Comment: Thank you, I have now imported my projects in Android Studio, but I'm getting some errors in xml like "could not resolve symbol "@string/title"". Can you help me with this one?

Comment: You'll get a ton of errors. I did not see that specific one when I imported mine however. The could not resolve symbol error though I did see and it was resolved after messing around with the dependencies in the build.gradle file of your app module.

Comment: Well, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: It's quite an in depth and specific-to-your-app process. Hunt around for a fix to your specific issue as what resolved mine probably isn't the same as yours. Either that or create a new question with more detail and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm going to give it a try!